# Use PNG or JPG for iPhone images downloaded from server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, cocoa-touch, png

I realize that PNG is normally the web standard, but I might have a bit of a unique situation. I'm building an app that downloads lots of images from a server. The download needs to be as quick as possible, especially over 3G connections. I've been looking into the best compression for the images on the server. Ideally, every image I use can be quickly resized for the app using a drag and drop converter of some sort. When I convert one of the images to a PNG, the file size is around 130KB. When converted to an acceptable JPG quality however, the file size comes in at well under 50KB. Should I use JPGs in the application?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually depends on the type of images.
The basic rule is to use JPEG for photos and PNG for everything else.

Why is it so?
JPEG compression is designed for photos - photos can handle lossy compression. On the other hand, PNG is compression designed for images which have similar pixels close to each other (straight lines, areas filled with one color, texts, etc.). If you try to use JPEG on an image which is not a photo, you'll be surprised - it won't look very good.

PNG is a standard - but for icons, backgrounds, patterns etc; not for photos.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use jpg. You will not encounter any problem. It is a tradeoff between quality and size. Jpeg is usually smaller because it is compressed so as to reduce size. Png is lossless compressed.

I have made applications that use both png and jpeg and they both work like a charm.

EDIT: You can also check out this link [PNG vs JPEG](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/jpeg-vs-png-image-quality-or-bandwidth/5385/)

Comment: PNG is compressed, of course! It's just targeted for another type of images. It's called "lossless" compression.

Answer (score 0):

PNG images are huge in size, use JPG as long as it's possible (when you don't need transparency)